# How can i reverse the table row order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to reverse the table row order , with the exception of the first/last row. Have a jsfiddle set up , that is reversing all tr but need to make last row and first row exempt for script

http://jsfiddle.net/Ybyjx/6/

```
   <table id="league_chat">
        <tbody>
            <tr><td>ALWAYS LEAVE THIS TR AT THE TOP/td></tr>
            <tr><td>lots of custom content</td></tr>
            <tr><td>lots of other custom content</td></tr>
            <tr><td>more custom content</td></tr>
            <tr><td>even more custom content</td></tr>
            <tr class="reportfooter"><td>ALWAYS LEAVE THIS TR AT THE BOTTOM</td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

tbody = $('#league_chat tbody');
tbody.children().each(function (i, tr) {
    tbody.prepend(tr);
});
```

Comment: Use footer and headers

Comment: Can't you use `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `get()` to get the native nodeList, then `reverse()` to reverse it, and just add it back.
The last one is excluded with `not()`

```
var tbody = $('#league_chat tbody');

$('tr:first', tbody).after( $('tr', tbody).not(':last', ':first').get().reverse() );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybyjx/25/)

Comment: ty , how can i make it so first and last rows are not changed ? I updated my post

Answer (score 1):

```
tbody = $('#league_chat tbody');
tbody.children().not(':first').not(":last").each(function (i, tr) {
    tbody.find('tr:first').after(tr);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In most circumstances where you need to keep the first row and last row constant you probably need to use a header and footer [Sample Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/Ybyjx/8/)

```
<table id="league_chat">
    <thead>
        <tr><td>ALWAYS LEAVE THIS TR AT THE TOP</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>        
        <tr><td>lots of custom content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>lots of other custom content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>more custom content</td></tr>
        <tr><td>even more custom content</td></tr>        
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr class="reportfooter"><td>ALWAYS LEAVE THIS TR AT THE BOTTOM</td></tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: can not change the html

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to do it.

```
 tbody.children().not('.reportfooter').each(function (i, tr) {
        $('#league_chat tbody tr:first').after(tr);
    });
```